# Customizing orchard theme parts

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am trying to write a custom theme for orchard and am not having much success so far. I have read [Bertrand Le Roy's](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx) article on part alternates but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am displaying a list of recent blog posts on the front page, pretty standard. I wish to change the markup produced by the meta data part i.e the time format.

I have written a `IShapeTableProvider` to create blog specific alternates for the metadata summary part.

```
public class MetaDataShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
{
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor;

    public MetaDataShapeProvider(IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor)
    {
        this.workContextAccessor = workContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
          .Describe("Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary")
          .OnDisplaying(displaying =>
          {
              ContentItem contentItem = displaying.Shape.ContentItem;
              if (contentItem != null)
                displaying.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("Metadata__" + contentItem.ContentType);
          });
    }
}
```

This is being caught correctly but the contentItem is null. Should I just create an alternate with a fixed name like "Metadata-BlogPost" and use that, to make this general purpose it should really be a dynamic name so I can use another alternate template elsewhere.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the content item from content part for which the shape is rendered, like:

```
displaying.Shape.ContentPart.ContentItem;
```

Instead of

```
displaying.Shape.ContentItem;
```

The **Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary** shape gets a related content part object passed as a named parameter **ContentPart**, so that should do.

HTH